# How zooming Google Maps works regarding the new projection?

Tags: google-maps, vector-tiles

Please help understanding how tiles now work on Google Maps.

As I understand (these are all assumptions, please feel free to correct) the following happens:

- Google Maps now work with orthographic projection;
- When we zoom from the globe to a territory, the orthographic projection remains; so **the first question is**, as an orthographic projection is a view from an infinitely distant point of perspective, Google Maps probably had to precalculate a lot of zooms for a lot of territories?
- If that's true, what happens when we drug the map? Are all the tiles recalculated? (**That's the second question**).
- **The third and the main question is**: if the Web Mercator projection is not used anymore, how do tiles zoom? In my understanding, the whole Web Mercator thing was making the map flat, thus cuttable in squares, each square (tile) duplicating each quadrupling each time we zoom. But if the tiles are no longer square, how do they quadruple?

Comment: Web Mercator projection is used for the Google Map API still (only pricing changes in July 2018 for use)

Comment: The Globe View in Google Maps uses a Vertical Near-Side Perspective projection (Earth from space), not an orthographic one. The point of view is at a finite distance above a point and it changes as you pan and zoom in Google Maps.